# Modify position of colorbar so that extend triangle is above plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar

So, I have to make a bunch of `contourf` plots for different days that need to share colorbar ranges. That was easily made but sometimes it happens that the maximum value for a given date is above the colorbar range and that changes the look of the plot in a way I dont need. The way I want it to treat it when that happens is to add the extend triangle above the "original colorbar". It's clear in the attached picture.

[image]

I need the code to run things automatically, right now I only feed the data and the color bar range and it outputs the images, so the fitting of the colorbar in the code needs to be automatic, I can't add padding in numbers because the figure sizes changes depending on the area that is being asked to be plotted.

The reason why I need this behavior is because eventually I would want to make a `.gif` and I can't have the colorbar to move in that short video. I need for the triangle to be added, when needed, to the top (and below) without messing with the "main" colorbar.

Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize, BoundaryNorm
from matplotlib import  cm

###############
## Finds the appropriate option for variable "extend" in fig colorbar
def find_extend(vmin, vmax, datamin, datamax):
    #extend{'neither', 'both', 'min', 'max'}
    if datamin >= vmin:
        if datamax <= vmax:
            extend="neither"
        else:
            extend="max"
    else:
        if datamax <= vmax:
            extend="min"
        else:
            extend="both"
    return extend


###########
vmin=0
vmax=30
nlevels=8
colormap=cm.get_cmap("rainbow")

### Creating data
z_1=30*abs(np.random.rand(5, 5))
z_2=37*abs(np.random.rand(5, 5))
data={1:z_1, 2:z_2}
x=range(5)
y=range(5)


## Plot
for day in [1, 2]:
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4)) 
    ## Normally figsize=get_figsize(bounds) and bounds is retrieved from gdf.total_bounds 
    ## The function creates the figure size based on the x/y ratio of the bounds
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

    norm=BoundaryNorm(np.linspace(vmin, vmax, nlevels+1), ncolors=colormap.N)
    z=data[day]
    cs=ax.contourf(x, y, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
    extend=find_extend(vmin, vmax, np.nanmin(z), np.nanmax(z))
    fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap), ax=ax, extend=extend)

    plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: Adjust the shrink and aspect parameters?  But I would just always show the extends.  I’m not sure why you want them winking in/out.

Comment: I will change the `extend` colors later on with `set_over` and `set_under` which is why I need it to show up when needed. I don't know if the `shrink` parameter would do anything because I am not sure if the extend triangle is a percentage of the y axis range, of the data values or of a given set width. I have seen plots online with long extend triangles and others with shorter so I am not sure if `shrink` would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this: putting a triangle on top of the colorbar manually:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pc = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.randn(20, 20))

cb = fig.colorbar(pc)

trixy = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 1], [0.5, 1.05]])
p = mpatches.Polygon(trixy, transform=cb.ax.transAxes, 
                     clip_on=False, edgecolor='k', linewidth=0.7, 
                     facecolor='m', zorder=4, snap=True)
cb.ax.add_patch(p)
plt.show()
```

[image]